# Adding tags to the beginning and end of the filename is stuck in a loop when there are more than 500 files in a folder- How to avoid this?

Tags: loops, batch-file, infinite

We receive files from an organization and the filename is typically in numbers:  `123456789.dat` and I have a batch script that will add a prefix and a new suffix to the filename, IE:

```
COMPANY-1-123456789.dat.txt
```

The code works exactly as it should, BUT when there are over 500 files in the folder, the append function will keep adding the prefix and suffix many times over and over and it would not stop, IE:

```
COMPANY-1-COMPANY-1-COMPANY-1-COMPANY-1-123456789.dat.txt.txt.txt.txt
```

I had to kill the batch script and split up the number of files into two smaller groups and that would work just fine.  Unfortunately, I won't always be around to catch this problem and would like to prevent this from happening again.

Did exhaustive search over the internet but could not find anything remotely similar to what I am looking for.  If this problem exists elsewhere, would you please point me to the question?  It would be greatly appreciated.

We have several different companies that send us numerous files on a daily basis so the code I pasted would have at least 10 different companies involved; it is basically a repeat of the below snippet all on one batch file.  Only one company is sending us more than 500 files and I would need to manually split them up into groups of two in order to get the code working properly.  Anything over 500 would just get caught in a loop.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
CHDIR /D "v:\DIR\COMPANY_NAME\ORIGFILE"
for %%a in (*.*) do ren "%%a" "COMPANY-1-%%a.TXT"
XCOPY /Q /Y "*.TXT" "C:\Local_dir\Sub_Folder\"
MOVE /Y "*.TXT" "COMPLETED\"
```

Comment: if the original files have a `.dat`extension, why don't you use that in the for command? `for %%a in (*.dat) do ren "%%a" "COMPANY-1-%%a.TXT"`

Comment: @LotPings Not all files will have `*.dat` extension.  I use `*.*` to include all extensions.  Is `*.*` the problem here?

Comment: Well the symptoms indicate files are processed multiple times, are there also .txt files on the input side?

Comment: BTW, thanks for editing my post for clarity!  Appreciate that!

Comment: @LotPings, there are no `.txt` in the original filename.  My company requires the added extension for easier upload to another, different program.  How do I stop this symptom from happening?  Thanks!

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, but I have a theory that it's caused by the `*.*` and that it might get fixed if you change it to `dir /b *.*`. It's either caused by the maximum string size being exceeded or by the fact that the order of the files changes when the files are renamed and `*.*` checks constantly instead of just once.

Comment: Change `for %%a in (*.*) do ren "%%a" "COMPANY-1-%%a.TXT"` by `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /A:-D /B *.*') do ren "%%a" "COMPANY-1-%%a.TXT"`

Comment: @Aacini, trying your line today.  I'm assuming `'dir /a:-d /b *.*'` will exclude the subfolder and rename just the files only?  We are scheduled to get in excess of 500 files today so we will see if that works.  I'll report back with results.  Thank you!

Comment: @Aacini.  This works!  Thank you!

Comment: @Aacini, yesterday, we had over 900 files and the code ended up adding tags in a loop for some reason.  It was a good try for a week and then it stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple FOR command does not scan the entire directory before iterating. Rather it scans until some buffer is full, processes that buffer, and then tries to pick up scanning where it left off. But if you have renamed files, it can confuse the scanning process - the rename operation can change where the file appears in the folder listing such that the resumed scan picks up an already renamed file.

This problem can only arise when the number of files exceeds the internal FOR buffer.

The fix is to use FOR /F with DIR /B instead, as that buffers the entire result of the DIR command before it begins iterating.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d-h-s *.*') do ren "%%a" "COMPANY-1-%%a.TXT"
```

Comment: This will actually rename my output folder, which resides in this directory: `v:\DIR\COMPANY_NAME\ORIGFILE`.  The output folder is named `v:\DIR\COMPANY_NAME\ORIGFILE\COMPLETED`.  Is there an another way that does not rename the folder, just the files?  Thank you.

Comment: @rtuteur - Oops, yes. I forgot to include `/a-d-h-s` to mimic the output of `FOR`. The `-d` excludes directories, `-h` excludes hidden files, and `-s` excludes system files. I edited the answer. Thanks

Comment: This works as well!  Thank you!!!